# Why isn't my Intellij IDE opening properly

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running OSX version 10.9.5 and IntelliJ version 2019.2.3(IC-192.6817.14). When I open my IntelliJ IDE, I don't see the editor[image]

[image]

This is all I can see. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: An empty screenshot doesn't help too much. Find the IntelliJ log files and include what is relevant here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519

Answer (score 2):

As per official documentation 2019.2 requires macOS 10.11 or later.

> Officially released 64-bit versions of the following:
>
> Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 or later
>
> macOS 10.11 or later
>
> Any Linux distribution that supports Gnome, KDE, or Unity DE
>
> Pre-release versions are not supported.

Ref: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html#requirements

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install the official [Jetbrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) to handle installation/upgrade of your IDE(s). I (hope) it is aware of OS limitations and won't propose you upgrade to something non-functional. What it definitely *does* do is to  rollback to an earlier installation with a single click.

Toolbox will detect and handle your existing manual installation so there's no penalty to installing it right now and seeing what options it gives (e.g. 2019.2.4 is out maybe incompatible as other answer hints or may be some bug is fixed!)